# Pointer with no initialization in Visual studio 2015 and in c++ language

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

Consider this simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void* voidptr;
    cout << voidptr << endl;

}
```

Here is the error:[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9oVp.png)

When I run this in visual studio 2015 I get a Debug error but when I do this in code blocks the program works with no error.I read in my textbook that we can use a pointer without initialization but now I can't do it in visual studio.
Does anybody know that what the problem is?

Here is my textbook:[Object-oriented programming in c++ by Roabert Lafore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANUqK.png)

Comment: Didn't you get a warning such as `local variable 'voidptr' used without having been initialized` during the compilation ?`

Comment: Change `void* voidptr;`-> to `void* voidptr = NULL;` and try again.

Comment: No, you cannot use a pointer without initialization. Either you misunderstand what is written in your book, or your book is lying to you. The compiler doesn't have to (but is allowed to) warn you, crash your program, or format your hard disk if you do that,

Comment: I uploaded the error screen shot

Comment: @MichaelWalz I did 'void* voidptr = NULL;' It didn't get any error but it printed: 0000000

Comment: @n.m. I uploaded my textbook.take a look at it please

Comment: The book says very clearly: "before the pointer can be used, a specific address must be placed in it".

Comment: @n.m. in "to summarize"section says something else.

Comment: No it doesn't, please quote where you think it does.

Comment: @n.m.Here:" However,it must be given some value,or it will point to an address we don't want it to point to,such as into our program code or the operating system."

Comment: What exactly gives you permission to use a pointer that points to an operating system?

Comment: @n.m. Actually I'm a beginner.I don't know.

Comment: Ok so the answer is nothing (and it's correct too). If you try to use such pointer your program may crash. Or it may not. Or it may format your hard disk. This is what called *undefined behavior* in C and C++. You have to avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile this program, the compiler warns you that `voidptr` is used without having been initiaslized in this line: `cout << voidptr << endl;

When you run this program you get this error:

[image]

Which again tells you that `voidptr`is being used without beiing initialized. This can hardly be clearer.

In C and C++ local variables are not initialized, they contain what ever value has been in memory before, the values are undeterminate. Now when you run the debug version of a program, you get this debug message, because the compiler is kind enough to show you that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Try to run the release version of the program, you won't get any more error, but some apparently random value will be displayed.

Comment: How can I run a release version?Is there any shortcut?

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian in the toolbar you have a drop down list containing the word "Debug". Click there and choose "Relese", then compile and run again.

Comment: I couldn't find it.Please look at the "temp" picture I posted in my question!

Comment: Would you briefly tell me what is the difference  between debug mode and release mode?Thank you very much.

Comment: @MohammadGhanatian that's too long to explain here: google this: _debug vs release build_

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read from an unitialized variable, be it a pointer or other type (note that for classes default initialization is usually equal to zero initialization, which would make the syntax used valid). Doing so yields undefined behavior.

You could fix the problem of `voidptr` being unitialized by initializing it

```
void* voidptr = nullptr;
```

but this won't help should you try to dereference it. In this case you would need to point it somewhere, either allocated by `new`/`malloc` and the likes, or to some already existing object.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your behaviour is *undefined* so anything can happen.

As [[dcl.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init) says in paragraph 12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   ([expr.ass]). [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration
>   are zero-initialized, see [basic.start.static].  — end note ] If an
>   indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, **the behavior is
>   undefined** except in the following cases:
>
> .. insert cases that don't apply to your case here

So your results do not matter. A good compiler should've at least warned you about this.